# Excel macro to create line chart excluding columns in between

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I want to create line chart in excel macro. I have below table in excel.

[image: Excel Snapshot]

First Line Chart contains range of values from Cell A and B. Second Line Chart contains range of values from Cell A and C. Third Line Chart contains range of values from Cell A and D.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:D3")
ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
```

Above code produces only one Line Chart for range A1 to D4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question that the macro recorder can provide a good hint on how to answer.  You just need to define another series collection.  Here is what the macro recorder produces without modification.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1:D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2")
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet1!$A$3"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$3:$D$3"
End Sub
```

---

[image]

---

Here is how I would do it without using select

```
Sub createChart()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set chrt = wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    With chrt
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$D$2")
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=Sheet1!$A$3"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=Sheet1!$B$3:$D$3"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Looping**

```
Sub createChartWithLoop()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set chrt = wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    Dim chartRange As Range
    Set chartRange = wks.Range("A1:A4")

    With chrt
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(wks.Range("A" & chartRange.Row & ":D" & chartRange.Row).Address)

        For i = chartRange.Row + 1 To chartRange.Rows.Count
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(i).Name = wks.Cells(i, 1)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Values = wks.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** - Create different charts from each **row** of data

```
Sub createDifferentCharts()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim chartRange As Range
    Set chartRange = wks.Range("A1:A4")

    For i = chartRange.Row To chartRange.Rows.Count
        With wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(wks.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Address)
            .Parent.Left = 20 + i * 50
            .Parent.Top = 40 + i * 50
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

---

Create different charts for each **column** of data with column A being the labels:

```
Sub createDifferentCharts()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim chartRange As Range
    Set chartRange = wks.Range("A1:D4")

    For col = chartRange.Column + 1 To chartRange.Columns.Count
        With wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlLine
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(wks.Cells(1, 1).Address)
            .SetSourceData Source:=wks.Range("A1:A4," & Range(Cells(chartRange.Row, col), Cells(chartRange.Rows.Count, col)).Address)
            .Parent.Left = col * 30
            .Parent.Top = col * 30
        End With
    Next col
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I want to generate 3 different graphs. Graph 1 - X Axis Cell A1:A4, Y Axis Cell C1:C4.  Graph 2 - X Axis Cell A1:A4, Y Axis  Cell B1:B4.  Graph 3 - X Axis Cell A1:A4, Y Axis - Cell D1:D4.

Comment: Okay, see my edit. The last code block will create different line charts for each column of data using column A as the axis labels.  Is this what your looking for?

Comment: Above code works fine. However sometimes I am receiving Automation Error Unspecified error -2147467259. I am not receiving above error if I debug the function. However I am receiving above error only if I press F5(Direct Run)