# How to create Line charts?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create Line charts (2-D Line with Markers) for a set of records.

Screenshot of Excel tab
[image: Screenshot of Excel tab]

(a) Every three rows represent a set to be charted. The fourth column, though it appears, need not be charted. In the screenshot there are 18 rows, which is six sets of records.

(b) One Line chart required for each set of records. Hence a total of six charts to be created automatically.

(c) Also, the charts are to be created in different Excel tabs. Three charts per tab, hence this should create two Excel tabs with three charts placed in each tab.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674275/excel-macro-to-create-line-chart-excluding-columns-in-between

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel macro to create line chart excluding columns in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674275/excel-macro-to-create-line-chart-excluding-columns-in-between)

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared some code for automatic charts generation using VBA macro in excel see if this helps.

Below code will generate charts for data available in excel:

```
Dim Startrow As String
Dim Lastrow As String
Dim Lastcolumn As String
Dim ws1 As String
Dim cs2 As String
Dim cs3 As String
Dim ws(100)
Dim count As String
Dim i As Integer


Sub Final()
For j = 2 To Sheets.count
    count = Sheets.count
    Sheet1.Activate
    Cells(i, 1) = Sheets(i).Name
    'ws(i) = Sheets(i).Name
    'MsgBox Sheets.Count
    'MsgBox count
    'MsgBox ws(i)
Next

For i = 2 To count
    MsgBox count
    MsgBox i
    Sheet1.Activate
    ws(i) = Cells(i, 1)
    Sheets(ws(i)).Activate
    'Sheets(ws(i)).Activate
    MsgBox ws(i)
    'MsgBox Range("B1")
    'MsgBox IsEmpty(Range("B2"))
    If IsEmpty(Range("B1")) = False Then
        Startrow = 2
        'MsgBox Startrow
        Lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'MsgBox Lastrow
        Lastcolumn = Split(Columns(Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).Address(, False), ":")(1)
        'MsgBox Lastcolumn
        Call test1
        MsgBox i
    End If
Next

End Sub

Function test1()

Dim letter As String
Dim letter1 As String
Dim letter2 As String
Dim letter3 As String

Dim x As Integer
MsgBox ws(i)
x = Range(Lastcolumn & 1).Column
'MsgBox x

Dim cs As Worksheet
Set cs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
'ws.name = "PrivateBytes_000005_Charts"
'ws2 = "PrivateBytes_000005_Charts"
cs.Name = ws(i) + "_Charts"
'MsgBox ws.Name
cs2 = ws(i) + "_Charts"
MsgBox cs2
cs3 = ws(i)
MsgBox cs3

If x < 27 Then

    For i = 2 To x



        letter3 = Chr(64 + i)

        'chart command

          Sheets(cs2).Activate
          ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
          ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(cs3).Range("A" & Startrow & ":A" & Lastrow & "," & letter3 & Startrow & ":" & letter3 & Lastrow)

          With ActiveChart
              .HasTitle = True
              Sheets(cs3).Activate
              .ChartTitle.Text = Range(letter3 & "1").Value
              .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
              .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
          End With

    Next

End If

If x >= 27 Then

    For i = 2 To 26

        letter3 = Chr(64 + i)


        'chart command

        Sheets(cs2).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(cs3).Range("A" & Startrow & ":A" & Lastrow & "," & letter3 & Startrow & ":" & letter3 & Lastrow)


          With ActiveChart
              .HasTitle = True
              Sheets(cs3).Activate
              .ChartTitle.Text = Range(letter3 & "1").Value
              .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
              .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
          End With

    Next

    For i = 27 To x

        letter3 = Chr(Int((i - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(((i - 1) Mod 26) + 65)
        'MsgBox letter3

        'chart command

        Sheets(cs2).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineStacked).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(cs3).Range("A" & Startrow & ":A" & Lastrow & "," & letter3 & Startrow & ":" & letter3 & Lastrow)

          With ActiveChart
              .HasTitle = True
              Sheets(cs3).Activate
              .ChartTitle.Text = Range(letter3 & "1").Value
              .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
              .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
          End With

    Next
End If

Sheets(cs.Name).Activate
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Test1"
Call AutoSpace_Shapes_Vertical
'Return
'Unload UserForm1
End Function
Function AutoSpace_Shapes_Vertical()

'Automatically space and align shapes
    Sheets(cs2).Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll


Dim shp As Shape
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim dTop As Double
Dim dLeft As Double
Dim dHeight As Double
Const dSPACE As Double = 8

  'Check if shapes are selected
  If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Please select shapes before running the macro."
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Set variables
  lCnt = 1

  'Loop through selected shapes (charts, slicers, timelines, etc.)
  For Each shp In Selection.ShapeRange
    With shp
      'If not first shape then move it below previous shape and align left.
      If lCnt > 1 Then
        .Top = dTop + dHeight + dSPACE
        .Left = dLeft
      End If

      'Store properties of shape for use in moving next shape in the collection.
      dTop = .Top
      dLeft = .Left
      dHeight = .Height
    End With

    'Add to shape counter
    lCnt = lCnt + 1

  Next shp
End Function
'End Sub
'End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipO5X.jpg)